# LWC push fails with error "Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle selector."

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, push

I am trying to follow this [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics/add-styles-and-data-to-a-lightning-web-component?trailmix_creator_id=00550000006yDdKAAU&trailmix_id=lightning-web-components) and I am trying to create a selector lightning web component with code

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';
const fields = [NAME_FIELD];

export default class Selector extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedProductId;
    handleProductSelected(evt) {
        this.selectedProductId = evt.detail;
    }
    userId = Id;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$userId', fields })
    user;
    get name() {
        return getFieldValue(this.user.data, NAME_FIELD);
    }
}
```

but it fails with error

> Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle selector.
>   [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Every Lightning Web Component requires component configuration file with file name ending .js-meta.xml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_meta_file)

This file can be created manually with `New File` menu item command in VS Code with manual insertion of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

or by selecting a menu item `SFDX: Create Lightning Web Component`
 or by a create command like suggested [in this topic](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lPFEQA2)

[sfdx force:lightning:component:create --type lwc  -n selector -d force-app/main/default/lwc/selector](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_lightning.htm)

where

-n : specifies the name of the LWC component

-d : specifies the directory or path

Answer (score 3):

You can also get this error if you have the component twice in your org. Perhaps an aura component with the same name, or different case in the naming.